# Text.insert(tk.INSERT ...) Method doesnt work properly in Python

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to display some sentences in "text.insert" method (GUI) of tkinter.
The sentences are the results of an another function.
I save the indexes of the lsit on another list but when i try to print all the 5 sentences i want it only prints 2 or 3.

I am trying to print them like these : Ans = sent[out[0]] , Ans1=sent[out[1]] ....
and i did 5 times , and at the end of the function i wrote :text1.insert(tk.INSERT , Ans,Ans1 ....)
As a result it only appears 2 or 3 sentences

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from collections import Counter
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter.messagebox import *


def my_function():
    global lastScore
    global out
    global sent

    filename = filedialog.askopenfile()
    fileReadyToRead = open(filename.name, 'r')
    file_contents = fileReadyToRead.read()

    data = file_contents

    data = file_contents
    word = word_tokenize(data)
    sent = sent_tokenize(data)

    a = len(sent)
    b = len(word)
    mo = b / a

    number = len(word)

    for x in range(0, number):
        map(str.lower, word[x])

    arraylist = [0] * b
    sentscore = [0] * a

    for x in set(word):
        for i in range(0, a):
            if x in sent[i]:
                sentscore[i] += word.count(x) / mo

    number = len(sent)

    sentList = [0] * number
    listaScore = [0] * number
    lastScore = [0] * number

    for x in range(number):
        sentList[x] = x + 1

    listaScore[0] = listaScore[0] + 0.5
    listaScore[number - 1] = listaScore[number - 1] + 0.5

    for i in range(0, number):
        lastScore[i] = listaScore[i] + sentscore[i]

    out = [i for i in sorted(range(len(lastScore)),
                             key=lastScore.__getitem__, reverse=True)][:5]


def show_answer():

    my_function()
    Ans = "Sentences :  \n",
    Ans0 = out
    Ans00 = out
    Ans1 = sent[out[0]]
    Ans2 = sent[out[1]]
    Ans3 = sent[out[2]]
    Ans4 = sent[out[3]]
    Ans5 = sent[out[4]]

    text1.insert(tk.INSERT, Ans, Ans0, Ans00, Ans1, Ans2, Ans3, Ans4, Ans5)


root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Programm")
text1 = tk.Text(root, heigh=25, width=70)


text1.pack()


button1 = Button(root, text='Result', command=show_answer)
button1.pack()


blank = Entry(root)


def close_window():
    root.destroy()


frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack()


buttonExit = Button(frame, text=" Exit ", command=close_window)
buttonExit.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The syntax is `insert(index, text, *tags)`: [Tkinter.Text.insert-method](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm#Tkinter.Text.insert-method). Do `text = '\n'.join([Ans1, Ans2, ...])`

Comment: Thats it, Really helped! Thanks

Comment: @stovfl: not quite. The syntax supports alternating pairs of text and tags (eg: insert(index, text, tag, text, tag, text, tag, ...).

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for the `insert` method is that it takes an index, a string, and then optionally, a list of tags, another string, a list of tags, another string, and so on. The canonical tcl/tk documentation describes it like this:

> pathName **insert** *index chars ?tagList chars tagList ...?*
>
> ...If multiple chars-tagList argument pairs are present, they produce
>   the same effect as if a separate pathName insert widget command had
>   been issued for each pair, in order. The last tagList argument may be
>   omitted.

Given this this statement:

```
text1.insert(tk.INSERT, Ans, Ans0, Ans00, Ans1, Ans2, Ans3, Ans4, Ans5)
```

... tkinter will interpret the arguments like this:

- tk.INSERT - index
- Ans - text to be inserted
- Ans0 - one or more tags
- Ans00 - text to be inserted
- Ans1 - one or more tags
- Ans2 - text to be inserted
- Ans3 - one or more tags
- Ans4 - text to be inserted
- Ans5 - one or more tags

If you are intending to insert multiple lines of text, the simplest solution is to join them together with newlines before passing them to the `insert` method:

```
data = "\n".join((Ans, Ans0, Ans00, Ans1, Ans2, Ans3, Ans4, Ans5))
text1.insert(tk.INSERT, data)
```